# Agenda php com login

Tags: php, login

Preciso fazer uma agenda com *login* onde eu faço meu cadastro no sistema e faço *login*.

Após o login, cadastro minhas linhas da agenda nos campos `lugar`, `pais` e `descrição`.

Posso guardar quantas linhas eu quizer na "minha pagina", após fazer *logout* , outra pessoa faz *login* na pagina e vê os dados dele e não os meus.

Não sei como fazer isso , guardar dados usando o `id` unico de cada usuario, e depois puxar os dados pelo `id` tanbem.

Comment: O que exatamente você tem dúvida? Na parte da estruturação de tabelas ou na parte da programação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exatamente da forma como pensou, a estrutura básica do banco de dados ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
[USUARIO]
id_usuario
login
senha

[LINHA] // Como chamou
id_linha
id_usuario // Correspondente a quem está cadastrando
numero
descricao
lugar
pais
```

Ao fazer login, você pode salvar o id do usuário na sessão e cadastra-lo junto com a linha no campo id_usuario

Ao listar suas linhas você irá filtrar pelo id do usuario que está logado, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM linha WHERE id_usuario = X ORDER BY descricao
```

Espero que ajude

Abraços

Comment: não estou conseguindo ainda man :( , tento salvar o id mas n estou conseguindo